# Wordpress Error "Invalid CSS" but the CSS referenced is not my CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, sass

[This is an image of the error I'm getting from Wordpress.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7UZ9.jpg)

In the photo you can see that the references is to my xampp file as well.  I don't know how to change that either.

My actual CSS is:

```css
 }
}
/*
.wp-block-column{
 p{
  font-size: 20px;
  i{
   font-size: 40px;
  }
 }
}
*/
/*********************
VIDEO STYLES
*********************/
```

I'm not sure why it's not reading the CSS in the theme.  I have emptied the cache from WP and the browser and I have deleted and reuploaded the theme as well.

Comment: Syntex are not correct, it should be like <code> .wp-block-column p{ font-size: 20px;}
.wp-block-column i{ font-size: 40px;} </code>

Comment: I'm using SASS and none of the changes I make on the file seem to work.  I even commented it out and nothing happened

Comment: I'm not an expert in SASS, did you regenerate CSS after making the change?

Comment: Yeah the style sheet is rendered in Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators), but your syntax should look something like this;

```
.wp-block-column p {
    font-size: 20px;
}


.wp-block-column p i {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: In my current style sheet, the whole portion is commented out, but its not changing anything.

Comment: So if you inspect the element, and un-comment can you see your changes being applied to <p> or <i> elements with the wp-block-column class?

Comment: No, its like none of the changes that i make in the theme are being registered.

Comment: Just based on the error you were getting it seems like a syntax error. Are you still getting that same error?